# How to Set Custom Order Number in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We have b2b model for one ecommerce website. They are generating Vendor order id in seperate column of sales_order_items table. Now i want to display vendor order id instead of magento order id.

```
 Order # 000000483 Pending
March 23, 2019
Reorder
```

I need this change in Customer , My Orders page. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for it. I did it by using di.xml file

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" type="My\Vendor\Block\Order\Info" />
```

I copied order/info.phtml to my vendor folder, Now i can display my vendor order id instead of magento original order id.

Complete Code As follows.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace My\Vendor\Block\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context as TemplateContext;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer as AddressRenderer;

/**
 * Invoice view  comments form
 *
 * @api
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Info extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'order/info.phtml';

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $paymentHelper;

    /**
     * @var AddressRenderer
     */
    protected $addressRenderer;

    /**
     * @param TemplateContext $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param PaymentHelper $paymentHelper
     * @param AddressRenderer $addressRenderer
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        TemplateContext $context,
        Registry $registry,
        PaymentHelper $paymentHelper,
        AddressRenderer $addressRenderer,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->addressRenderer = $addressRenderer;
        $this->paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Order # %1', $this->getOrder()->getVendorOrderId()));
        $infoBlock = $this->paymentHelper->getInfoBlock($this->getOrder()->getPayment(), $this->getLayout());
        $this->setChild('payment_info', $infoBlock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste the complete code and mark it so others may get use to this answer @DineshManne